# Define citation sorting in pandoc-citeproc

Tags: sorting, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I want to sort my bibliography first by year, then by other fields. If I want to create a `tex` file I can put something like this in the biblatx options:

```
sorting=ydnt
```

Which sorts by year (descending), name, title. Exactly what I want. But how can I achieve the same result when producing an html with Pandoc?

I read the docs for `pandoc-citeproc` and couldn't find anything like that.

Cheers.